# How to have Eclipse Scala-IDE + Spring-IDE plugins working together?

Tags: spring, scala, eclipse-plugin

According to http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Troubleshooting in order to have the Scala Eclipse plugin to work with eclipse 3.5 you must desintall your Spring-IDE pluging since the latter deactive the JDT Weaving. I had to do so.

Do you know any effective way to circumvent this, I'm an active Spring developer, for obvious reasons I also want to incorporate the Scala-IDE to my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for questions like this is [the Scala IDE user mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user).